# Position of parent div from child div

Tags: html, css

I have a child with a know position, but the parent wrapper has not it. And the parent wrapper have another child div that it is a label.

For example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 50px">
    <img src="icon.png" />
  </div>
  <span class="label">abcdefghijk</span>
</div>
```

[image: example]

Of course normally the label change the length and it must is center.

Comment: So id="parent" should be in center or what?

Comment: Yes, in the center of child.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `position: absolute` to do that. Using `display: inline-block` will do the trick.
 The `#parent`'s width will grow with the label's width.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#parent {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

#child {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6em;
}

.icon {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color:red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" style="">
    <i class="fa fa-heartbeat fa3 icon"></i>
  </div>
  <span class="label">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the position absolute of child because it is in a position of screen.

And I know the position of the child, but I don't know the position of parent and the lenght of text.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Sorry, but i don't quite understand what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Well, The position of image is from a PHP, the label is from PHP too, but I don't know the number of characters of this label (and of course I don't know how to see the font of the browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I used a trick with javascript, and only I wanted only to make it with CSS :( .

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test000</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chincheta">
            <img id="image" src="tux.png">
            <div id="label">
                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style type="text/css">
        #chincheta
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($("#chincheta").width() > $("#image").width()) {
                dif_width = $("#chincheta").width() - $("#image").width();

                x = $("#chincheta").offset()['left'];

                x = x - (dif_width / 2)

                $("#chincheta")
                    .css("left", x + "px")
                    .css("text-align", "center");
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```